# Dash to dock application drawer icons to big

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

Hello I use dash to dock and the icons under the app drawer are huge.
I've attempted to modify them through the gnome shell css without any luck 
nautilus slider doesn't change anything either. any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You can change the icon size from the Dash to Dock settings. To achieve this, just look for **Gnome Tweak Tools** in the application, look at **Extensions** tab, and click on the small wheel beside the **Dash to Dock** extension. Adapt the icon size according to your needs.

Comment: Yes. That is a possibility. But unfortunately it only adjust the dock icon sizes. I need to adjust the icons in the applications drawer.